# How can I allow a user to resize a window?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

Currently when someone uses my application if they resize it then everything but the window stays in the same place and it looks ugly. How do I resize it so that everything is sort of relative to one another? Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BroZer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Reload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Refresh();
        }

        private void Go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void Back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoBack();
        }

        private void Forward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoForward();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search?&ie=UTF-8&q=" + textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.ShowSaveAsDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: plz accept at least one answer if issue resolved

Answer (score 2):

If you are using WinForms, you can use [anchoring and docking](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908) for dynamic resizing.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Control have a property called Anchor you will need to set it so when user resize the window your controls will fit as per the window size automatically

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) or [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property of control. So, that your controls will be adjust if windows resizes.

Read these tutorial, very easy and understandable.

[Manage WinForm controls using the Anchor and Dock properties](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908)

[Working with Anchoring and Docking Properties](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2231/Working-with-Anchoring-and-Docking-Properties)